# Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin Fail On Init - Android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm currently building an app the will be using the Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin to communicate and authenticate users.

I had it working about a month ago, and then I was getting close to the end of development when I decided to upgrade to the newest version of Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin and Facebook SDK - now I cannot get it functioning.

I'm not sure if Facebook has changed something, or if Cordova Facebook Connect plugin has issues now - I am literally stuck :(

Here are the steps I'm taking and my results:

**NOTE: I have deleted all programs and SDK's from my computer each time before attempting this to eliminate any cross version issues.**

- Create a Facebook App (followed instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#create-app)

  - Add Android Platform To App
  - Create a Key Hash using 'keytool' on OSX

    - `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`
- Download latest Facebook SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip)
- Installed the Facebook APK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#install)

  - `./adb install ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.14/bin/FBAndroid-7.0.0.apk`
- Installed Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2
- Installed the latest Android SDK (followed instructions: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)
- Installed NodeJS (NPM 1.4.3) to install Cordova 3.4.1-0.1.0 (Terminal)

  - `sudo npm install -g cordova`
- Create Cordova Application

  - `cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"`
  - `cd hello`
  - `cordova platform add android`
  - `cordova build`
- Installed Cordova Facebook Plugin

  - Installing using the command line interface (CLI):

    - `cordova -d plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"`
    - `Fetching plugin "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git" via git clone`
    - `Installing "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" for android`
  - NOTE: I also have tried manual installing using the following instructions: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
- Open Eclipse > File > Import > + Android > select Existing Android Code into Workspace

  - Import `HelloWorld`
  - Select App Properties > Android > add FacebookSDK as a library
  - Copy the "Simple" example that came with Cordova Facebook Connect (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/example/Simple)
  - index.html is correctly linking to:

    - cordova.js
    - cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js
    - facebook-js-sdk.js
- Project > Clean
- Run with the Nexus S simulator

Once HelloWorld opens errors comes up:

- `Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on init`
- `Cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on auth.status`

**Like I said - I have tried manual installs and CLI installs, none will work!**

Other versions that I have tried:

- Cordova 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.4.0, 3.4.1
- Facebook SDK 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9
- Android Studio instead of Eclipse

This issue is causing major delay in our development and I have seen others online that are having the same problem, but no replies or answers.

*Thanks for any help!*

Answer (score 1):

Did you try fixing the target for config.xml for Facebook SDK 3.8.0 ?

`<config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>`

Answer (score 0):

As of 6/13/14 this is what works for me, so I laid out my steps on PasteBin.
http://pastebin.com/WvQvqx6U

Basically I just reverted FacebookConnect back to 0.4.0.